# How to store the data of filestream in SQL Server (each data in one row)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a filestream with a large number of data, I want to move these data to database so that each data is stored in one row of a table in SQL Server. How can I do this?

Comment: The answers you have so far seem to assume that you want to store a whole file in one row. I read your questions differently: I think that your individual rows are small, but your file contains many rows. Am I right?  If so, we'll need more detail to answer your question.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: That depends on the data in the file. How does the file look like?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use BLOBs (Binary Large Objects). They have a non-trivial impact on performance, though. See [here for an introduction.](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3719221)

Comment: I don't think so: I think the OP wants to split the file into multiple rows.  There's no reason that this would have to be a BLOB.

Comment: On second read I think you may be right, although that's a very weird question to ask, what does the data look like?

Comment: It's a basic question and a badly-written one, but that's nothing weird for StackOverflow :-)

Comment: my filestream contains numbers in hex mod, (the outputs of a function) I wavt to stire every 4 bytes of data in filestream in one row

Comment: And while you're at it, let us know what the database table looks like.

Comment: I have (2^32)-1=4294967295 numbers in binary or decimal format (these data are in 256 file stream, each file 16777216 data). The task is:counting the number of repetition of these numbers. I tried some ways but because the number of data and so the number of processing for task is many, So I get "out of memory exception" or "need a lot of time for processing", therefore I decided to use SQLServer DATABASE. Now I want to store each file in DB such that the data of file are saved as records, ie each nember in one record or row of datbase.

Comment: and I guess that I can count the number of repetitions by queries in SQL easily!!!!???

Comment: You should really edit your question, or post a new one, to reflect all this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the `FILESTREAM` data type?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(SQL.105).aspx